Why are the constructors of CardColors, TopAppBarColors, etc internal? In my other Project its not
The question is above
Is it because of different dependencies in the projects.
I post my dependencies of the current project below:
dependencies {
    // Retrofit
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
    // Retrofit with Kotlin serialization Converter

    implementation("com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.11.0")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    // Kotlin serialization
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")

    //Moshi
    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.14.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.14.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0")

    //load images from url
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0")
    //coils
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.4.0")
}

It is really confusing.
Android Studio always tells me to import CardColors but its already imported
when I try to build it tells me that the constructor is internal
